# Which branch do commits from a deleted branch belong to?

Tags: git, git-branch

If I merge branch A into branch B and then delete A, which branch do commits from branch A (now deleted) belong to?

Comment: It helps to remember that a "branch" in git is just a pointer to a commit. All the commits "on the branch" are ones that are reachable from that commit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Git branches are mere pointers to commits. Asking

> Which branch does this commit belong to?

doesn't really make sense (at least, not in the general case) because commits may very well be reachable from multiple branches (or even from none at all!).

Consider the following example:

[image]

Commit `F` is currently only reachable from the `bugfix` branch; at this point, it makes sense to say that commit `F` "belongs" to the `bugfix` branch. However, if you then merge `bugfix` into `master`, by running

```sh
git checkout master
git merge bugfix
```

then commit `F` becomes reachable from both of those branches:

[image]

Commit `F` can no longer be said to belong to `bugfix` more than to `master`.
If you then delete `bugfix`, commit `F` will again be reachable from only one branch, `master` this time, in which case it will make sense to say that commit `F` "belongs" to `master`.

---

In summary, a commit cannot, in general, be thought of as *exclusively* belonging to any one branch. However, a question that always *does* make sense is

> From which branches (if any) is this commit reachable?