# How to know which branch a spefic branch was rebased on to

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-log, git-reflog

I am using `git reflog` to get information about branches, as i need to know the name of the branch passed to the command.

for example when using `git rebase --onto master`, I need to know that `master` branch is used for rebasing. the problem is that `reflog` does not say which branch was used. Instead it shows the SHA of the commit that this branch was rebased onto.

check the following ref-log output (the branch was rebased onto `master`)

```
7f3a5b9 rebase-test/rebase-2@{1}: rebase finished: refs/heads/rebase-test/rebase-2 onto a9d523f1a73fe2cd2857ee3d013463069fe51c3d
5161e07 rebase-test/rebase-2@{2}: commit: adding rebase-file4
c8d0ed0 rebase-test/rebase-2@{3}: commit: adding rebase-file3
6ab1277 rebase-test/rebase-2@{4}: branch: Created from rebase-test/rebase-1
```

now I need to know which branch this commit SHA `a9d523f1a73fe2cd2857ee3d013463069fe51c3d` belonged to at the time of rebase. This should work even if master has moved on since that time.

I tried `git log` with multiple options but it returns the current state of the branches not at specific time.

How can I get this information? If not possible to get the exact reference (`master` in this case), perhaps it is possible to get all references of this commit at that time?

## EDIT

base on @Jubobs commit, may be i can rephrase the question to: Which references were associated with this commit at the time of rebase

Comment: *[...] I need to know which branch this commit [...] belonged to [...]* In the general case, a commit doesn't belong to any particular branch; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257491/which-branch-do-commits-from-a-deleted-branch-belong-to/29258814#29258814

Comment: may be i can rephrase the question to: `Which references were associated with this commit at the time of rebase`

Comment: You can only check the reflog for that, because there is nothing else that records the history of branches.