# What branch orphan commits belong to? (Git, Github)

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-commit

I have some *orphan* commits inside my Github repo. They are not present inside of any branch or my local repo, and I can only see them if I select a specific issue with the list of related commits.

Is there any way I can merge these commits into another branch of my choice?

[image]

Comment: Orphaned commits don't belong to _any_ branch. That's precisely what makes them orphans.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. Is there a way to merge these commits into a particular branch?

Comment: @FelipePeña You're looking at it the wrong way. [Commits should not be thought of as *belonging* to a branch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29257491/which-branch-do-commits-from-a-deleted-branch-belong-to/29258814#29258814).

Comment: @Jucobs ok, thanks for the link. Assuming one commit is not present in my local repo, and also it's not merged in master, how can I bring it into master ?

Answer (score 0):

> What branch orphan commits belong to? (Git, Github)

Well, by definition orphaned commits do not belong to any branch (*btw, it's a bit wrong to say this, better wording is 'which branch-tip commits have the specific commit in their hierarchy chain?'*), so I suppose the real question is...

> Is there any way I can merge these commits into another branch of my choice?

Surely it is. You can use `git cherry-pick` command to, [quoting the docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), **"apply the changes introduced by some existing commits"**. Here goes a simple example of how it can be used:

First, the repository is initialized:

```
> git init
> echo 1 > first.txt
> git add . && git commit -m "First commit"
[master (root-commit) a8871cd] First commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 first.txt
```

Then, the orphan commits are created (the easiest way is to create a branch, advance it a bit, then remove it):

```
> git checkout -b branch-to-remove
Switched to a new branch 'branch-to-remove'

> echo 1 > cherry.txt
> git add . && git commit -m "Cherry commit 1"
[branch-to-remove 7cd90f8] Cherry commit 1
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
create mode 100644 cherry.txt

> echo 2 >> first.txt
> git add . && git commit -m "Cherry commit 2"
[branch-to-remove 8289dee] Cherry commit 2
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)

> git checkout master
> git branch -D branch-to-remove
Deleted branch branch-to-remove (was 8289dee).
```

So branch is gone, but two commits - 7cd90f8 and 8289dee - are still there. Now the master branch is worked upon:

```
> echo 3 >> first.txt
> git add . && git commit -m "Second commit"
[master e0c199e] Second commit
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
```

Now we have a kind of situation you have in your hands: there are some changes applied somewhere, we need these changes to be applied onto the current branch. It's trivial to do with simple non-conflicting changes, like the one introduced in `Cherry commit 1`:

```
 > git cherry-pick 7cd90f8
[master 864dcbe] Cherry commit 1
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 cherry.txt
```

The picked commit is replayed, changes are applied, another commit is created, tip of master branch is advanced, life is good. But what happens with the next one?

```
> git cherry-pick 8289
error: could not apply 8289dee... Cherry commit 2
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

In fact, nothing really bad: as both commits - HEAD and the picked one - affected the same file, there's a classical conflict going there. Easy to check, easy to fix; just don't forget to `git add` all the resulting files and `git commit` them later.

Note that the commits that are result of cherry-pick have single parent only (they're similar to rebased commits in this case).